# Why does this code only pass compilation after adding an unused generic type parameter to the class?

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter

This code doesn't pass compilation:

```
class SomeClass {
    void doSomethink(List<Integer> params) { }
}

class AnotherClass {
    public void method() {
        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
        List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();

        someClass.doSomethink(list);
    }
}
```

But if `SomeClass` contains an unused type parameter `E` then this code will pass compilation successfully:

```
class SomeClass<E> {
    void doSomethink(List<Integer> params) { }
}

class AnotherClass {
    public void method() {
        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
        List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();

        someClass.doSomethink(list);
    }
}
```

Why does this make a difference? `E` is not used.

Comment: What does the error message say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to pass a `List<Long>` to a method that expects a `List<Integer>`. A `List<Long>` is not a sub-class of `List<Integer>`, so it's not allowed.

When you make your `SomeClass` class generic (by adding `E`), and then instantiate it with the raw type `SomeClass`, all the generic type parameters of all the methods and their arguments are erased, and the compiler allows you to pass any `List` to the `doSomethink()` method.

Note that you'll get the same compilation error in your second snippet if you change it to (i.e. don't use a raw `SomeClass` type):

```
class SomeClass<E> {
    void doSomethink(List<Integer> params) { }
}

class AnotherClass {
    public void method() {
        SomeClass<Integer> someClass = new SomeClass<>();
        List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();

        someClass.doSomethink(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Really nice catch. I didn't notice the raw type in his second snippet.

Comment: I can't understand why **all** generic types are erased in that case, could you provide the reference?

Comment: @AlexandrArhipov see [JLS 4.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) and also JLS 4.6